# Local storage JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm making a craft beer webpage, and I want users to type in their age before entering. The initial prompt works, but if I switch tabs and go back to home page I am prompted again.

Question: How do I only get one prompt and save it until user exits the whole webpage including navigating tabs.`

My script:

```html
<script>

function CloseWindow(){
window.open('','_self','');
window.close();
}
</script>

<script>
var age;
age = prompt("Please enter in your age: ");
if (age >= 21){
   alert("Age is valid");
}
else{
   alert("Not valid age");
   CloseWindow();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do a local storage to do per session `html5 storage`

Comment: setting a cookie would be an easy way to go.

Comment: I'd agree with @Nived . A cookie would be the best option. Or, if you can use PHP, set a session variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `window.localStorage` object to store the user's age. This will allow the information to persist through pages.

```
if (window.localStorage && !window.localStorage.age) {
     //Your code here to prompt the user's age and save it in window.localStorage.age
} else {
    //Your code here to prompt the user's age and save it in document.cookie
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it check for `localStorage` support first and fallback to cookies if not supported?

Comment: You're right. I've edited the example above to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example snippet on how you can incorporate `localStorage` by building on top of your code. You can clean it up for what you need. If you want an alternative that resets when you close your browser, you can just replace `localStorage` with `sessionStorage`.

```
 function CloseWindow() {
   window.open('', '_self', '');
   window.close();
 }

 var validAge = localStorage.getItem('validAge');
 if (!validAge) {
   var age;
   age = prompt('Please enter in your age: ');
   if (age >= 21) {
     alert('Age is valid');
     localStorage.setItem('validAge', 'true');
   } else {
     alert('Not valid age');
     localStorage.setItem('validAge', 'false');
     CloseWindow();
   }
 } else if (validAge === 'true') {
   alert('Age is valid');
 } else if (validAge === 'false') {
   alert('Not valid age');
   CloseWindow();
 }
```

This is a [link](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-storage-localstorage-and-sessionstorage) that shows some localStorage polyfills for outdated browsers.

Comment: Hey this worked perfect in Chrome,  but in IE I'm not even getting a popup box. Any ideas??

Comment: What version of IE are you using? If you are using below 8, then it won't be compatible. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage. If you want a polyfill for localStorage, check out the link in the bottom of my post. Click `f12` and look on top right tab for `Browser Mode`. Check the `Console` to see if there is an error regarding localStorage.

Comment: I've tried my IE, and it works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/w6bem9tp/.. Have you tried `f12` to see what browser version you're on? Try changing your setting to `bleed`.

Comment: I'm using IE 11.. I don't know if my HTML file is linked well with IE. My header is <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script> <![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you need to create a variable in the local storage and check its content before running the whole function again. I suggest you check online for tutorials how to do that, here's one I found for you : http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Here's an example of how to do it simply too :

```
//Get the variable from the local storage
var age = localStorage.getItem('age') || 0; //instead you get nothing

if (age >= 18) {
   //access the website
} else {
   //here's where you run your function
   //...

   //Set the local storage variable
   localstorage.setItem('age', age) //where *age* is the name of the function's variable

}
```

I hope this will helps ! Good luck ;)